# Restore welcome screen buffer when closed

Tags: buffers, start-up

How do I open startup/splash/welcome screen/message buffer (***GNU Emacs***) when it's not listed in `list-buffers` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M-: (fancy-about-screen)`, or call `(fancy-about-screen)` from your Lisp code.

It shows this:

[image]

This is GNU Emacs, one component of the GNU operating system.

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)
 of 2015-04-11 on LEG570
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Authors Many people have contributed code included in GNU Emacs
Contributing    How to contribute improvements to Emacs

GNU and Freedom Why we developed GNU Emacs, and the GNU operating system
Absence of Warranty GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Copying Conditions  Conditions for redistributing and changing Emacs
Getting New Versions    How to obtain the latest version of Emacs
Ordering Manuals    Buying printed manuals from the FSF

Emacs Tutorial  Learn basic Emacs keystroke commands
Emacs Guided Tour   See an overview of Emacs features at gnu.org

Comment: I think this should work for me but when I start emacs throug runemacs.exe it gives me slightly different screen. `(fancy-about-screen)` give **\*About GNU Emacs*** instead of **\*GNU Emacs***

Comment: Please see my alternative answer to get **\*About GNU Emacs\***

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer displays the fancy *about* screen, but I'm just going to add that if anybody wants the actual *startup* screen then do `M-: (fancy-startup-screen)`

[image]